# Unable to update existing lead from force.com site

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, leads, standard-objects, custom-controller

I have a requirement where I need to update an existing Contact in Salesforce from a Visualforce page on display of a Force.com site.

How can this be achieved, since there is no update permission on Standard objects.

Whatever I had tried is as below :

```
public without Sharing class ContactEditExt {

public PageReference CANCEL() {
    return null;
}

public Contact con;
public Id recordId;
public ContactEditExt() {
recordId = apexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
System.debug('>>>>>>>recordId'+recordId);
}

public Contact getcon()
{
    con = [Select Id, firstname, lastname, Account.name ,email, Double_OptIn__c, Double_OptIn_Time__c, Receive_Communication__c from Contact where Id =:recordID];
        return con;
}
public pageReference saveStatusChange(){
    if(con.Receive_Communication__c == true){
        con.Double_OptIn__c = true;
        con.Double_OptIn_Time__c = date.today();
    }
try{
    update con;
}
catch(exception e){
    System.debug('update Contact :'+e);
}
return null;
}
```

}

Visualforce Page:

```
    <apex:page sidebar="false" controller="ContactEditExt">
 <apex:form >
  <apex:sectionHeader title="Edit Contact for" subtitle=""/>
   <apex:pageBlock >
     <apex:pageBlockButtons >
       <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!saveStatusChange}"/>
       <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!CANCEL}"/>
     </apex:pageBlockButtons>
       <apex:pageBlockSection Title="Update my Records" columns="1" >
         <apex:inputText value="{!con.email}"/>
         <apex:inputText value="{!con.Account.name}" label="Company"/>
         <apex:inputText value="{!con.firstname}"/>
         <apex:inputText value="{!con.lastname}"/>
         <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!con.Receive_Communication__c}" label="I would like to receive communications from the Roundtable on Sustainable Biomaterials"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
     </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I recently answered same requirement on forum.. You should have a look here. You cannot bind variables to Object if Force.com site user doesn't have permission for that object. You have to use apex wrapper.  
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/217518/19118

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A VF controller without sharing can update any record.  But if you put the record directly on the page and it has an "ID", the fields won't be writable.

So if you want to do an update, there's two workarounds:

- Use input tags on your page not associated with the existing object.  Then in your save method in your controller, put the values in the sObject you want to update.
- Store the ID of the object, create a new instance of the object, then during the save, update the ID.

Comment: Hello Tushar, I have added whatever I have tried above in the question. Can you please assist based on your previous response, that what I am supposed to do?

Comment: @ShobhitSaxena in your `getCon` try to clean the Id and then check.