# how to update(not Insert) a standard object(Account) record using sites

Tags: standard-objects

I created a site where the guest users can edit their personal information. the operation should be on the Account object.so I created a extentsion submit which will save the edited info by a user. It worked fine in the developer mode when I put that page in sites it's not updating the information on the lead record. when I went to public access settings and checked there are no modify permission for accounts on sites. how can I achieve this task through sites? I want to update the record not insert the record.

```
public Without Sharing class ExtensionExample{
    public String currentRecordId {get;set;}
    public String parameterValue {get;set;}
    List<Account> accRecords = new List<Account>();
    public Account acc{get;set;}
    public string accountName;
    public id accID;

    public ExtensionExample(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        currentRecordId  = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');
        acc = [select id ,name, AccountNumber, Type, Industry from Account where id =: currentRecordId ];
        parameterValue = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('nameParam');
    }
    public void  doSubmit() {
        accountName = acc.name;
        accID = acc.id;
        accRecords.add(new Account(id= accID, name=accountName));
        update accRecords;

    }
}
```

// vf page

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="ExtensionExample">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Current account record Id is : {!currentRecordId}" collapsible="false">
                <apex:InputField value="{!acc.name}"/>
                <apex:InputField value="{!acc.AccountNumber}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!acc.Type}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!acc.Industry}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>



            <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!doSubmit}"/>

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see from your code you are using a standard controller with extension. You have to kick that out in order to achieve what you want. Standard controllers always run in user mode and hence won't allow you to get extra access on record /object which are not allowed by Guest user license.

You cannot directly bind Account's field in Visualforce page, You have to use a custom apex class as wrapper for the reasons I have mentioned above.

```
public Without Sharing class ExtensionExample{

    public class AccountWrapper{
        String Name;
        String AccountNumber;
        String Type;
        String Industry;
        String Id;

    } //A custom wrapper class to fool VF UI
    public AccountWrapper accountw {get;set;} // Bind Variable for VF.


    public ExtensionExample() {


        String recId  = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id'); //Fetch recordId from params
        acc = [select id ,name, AccountNumber, Type, Industry from Account where id =: recId ];

        //Convert Account into wrapper
        accountw = new AccountWrapper();
        accountw.Id = acc.Id;
        accountw.Name = acc.Name;
        accountw.AccountNumber = acc.AccountNumber;
        accountw.Type = acc.Type;
        accountw.Industry = acc.Industry;



    }
    public void  doSubmit() {
        //Convert back wrapper into Account
        Account toBeUpdatedAccount = new Account ();
        toBeUpdatedAccount.Id =accountw.Id;
        toBeUpdatedAccount.Name =accountw.Name;
        toBeUpdatedAccount.AccountNumber =accountw.AccountNumber;
        toBeUpdatedAccount.Type =accountw.Type;
        toBeUpdatedAccount.Industry =accountw.Industry; 
        //Do DML
        update toBeUpdatedAccount;

    }
}
```

As you ditched standard controller your VF will be.

```
<apex:page Controller="ExtensionExample">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Current account record Id is : {!accountw.Id}" collapsible="false">
                <apex:InputField value="{!accountw.name}"/>
                <apex:InputField value="{!accountw.AccountNumber}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!accountw.Type}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!accountw.Industry}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>



            <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!doSubmit}"/>

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

VF won't allow you to bind Account fields, you have to fool VF's runtime engine by using an Apex class wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

Create A Custom Object "MyLead__C" and create all those fields present on Lead on that custom object.

Write a After Insert/ After Update trigger on MyLead__C

```
trigger MyLeadTrigger on MyLead__C(after insert,after update){

     MyLeadTriggerHandler.createLead(Trigger.new);

}
```

Apex Trigger Handler.

```
 public without sharing class MyLeadTriggerHandler{
          public static void createLead(List<MyLead__C> leadListNew){
    List<Lead> toBeInsertedUpdatedLead = new  List<Lead> ();
          List<SObject> toBeDeletedCustomObject = new  List<SObject>();
          for(MyLead__C mylead : leadListNew){
            Lead lead =new Lead();
            lead.Name = mylead.Name__c; // Copy All fields from Custom Object to lead
            //If its update operation then populate the Id of lead
            toBeInsertedUpdatedLead.add(lead);
            toBeDeletedCustomObject.add(mylead);
          }

          upsert toBeInsertedUpdatedLead;


          delete toBeDeletedCustomObject;// Delete the custom object record to save storage.
    }
    }
```

As we cannot do DML on Lead in Guest user context we would do DML on Custom Object, as Trigger Runs in System mode, it allows you to access objects that you dont even have access.

This is called as God Mode Abuse: http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/system-mode-or-god-mode-in-apex-gotchas/